# Check if activity is running from non-Activity class

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I want to check if activity is running from regular class (non-Activity) but the application is crashing and giving me `NullPointerException` and i did set `permission  GET_TASKS`
here is the LogCat output

```
    01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.evolution.betting.application/net.evolution.betting.application.InitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at net.evolution.betting.application.ConnectionChangeReceiver.checkIsNotationActive(ConnectionChangeReceiver.java:58)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at net.evolution.betting.application.ConnectionChangeReceiver.<init>(ConnectionChangeReceiver.java:20)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at net.evolution.betting.application.InitActivity.onCreate(InitActivity.java:30)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 13:38:38.703: E/AndroidRuntime(5595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

here is my source

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Context c;
    public ConnectionChangeReceiver(Context c){
        checkIsNotationActive();
        this.c = c;
    }

  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
    if ( activeNetInfo != null && checkIsNotationActive() == true)
    {

        ((NotationActivity)(context)).finish();

    }else if( activeNetInfo == null){

        Intent i = new Intent("net.evolution.betting.application.NOTATIONACTIVITY");
        i.putExtra("DialogTitle", "Warining!");
        i.putExtra("DialogBody", "It seems like your app is not connected to Internet witch is required.Please check your network connection.");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        context.startActivity(i);

    }


  }

  private boolean checkIsNotationActive(){


          ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)c.getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
              List<RunningTaskInfo> activitys = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
              boolean isActivityFound = false; 
              for (int i = 0; i < activitys.size(); i++) { 
                  if (activitys.get(i).topActivity.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ComponentInfo{net.evolution.betting.application/net.evolution.betting.application.NotationActivity}")) {
                      isActivityFound = true;
                  }
              } 
              return isActivityFound; 

  }
}
```

Comment: LogCat output? Where is the stack trace? Which line throws the NPE? So many open questions...

Comment: i've put the logcat output

Comment: And line 58 is which one?

Comment: this is the 58 line ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)c.getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as because your `c` Context instance is `null` move your code inside `onReceive` and use context for accessing System Service :

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Context c;

  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
     this.c = context;  //<<<<<<<  

     // your code here
  }

}
```

Comment: no need to have a context variable if you get the context as a parameter but the solution is basically correct. Use the context parameter instead of the context member variable.

Comment: @WarrenFaith : yes you are right but OP want to access context variable outside of onReceive .then first way is declare an Context variable at class level and assign context to it inside onReceive and second way is OP can pass context as Parameter to other method

Comment: True, I missed the private method. Anyway I would recommend the parameter solution. Anyway, upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant find where the problem is, but maybe, you can try the following method:
As you are using a broadcast receiver, why not try to send a broadcast(A) in the "onCreate()" of "NotationActivity" and another broadcast(B) in the "onDesdroy()".
Then, you can check if the activity is running by checking a variable, maybe an integer initialized to 0, changed to 1 when A received, and 2 when B received.